# :hover{} precedence in gecko

Tags: css, hash, hover

writing somewhat of a css hack, styling for :hover {} works interestingly, but browsers treat `a:hover` differently for full links VS hash tags.

from http://inqdrops.com/welcom/

`a, a:active, a:visited { color: #765; text-decoration: none;}

:hover { color: #ff5e99; text-decoration:overline; background: #222}`

for this code, hovers on `<a href='http://what.eva/'></a>` and `<a href='#whateva'></a>` behave differently. They also differ for webkit and gecko.

Can someone explain what is happening?

--
EDITED FOR EXPLANATION ON SOLUTION

the answer by @babtek pointed me in the right direction, and the solution was to expand the css rule to `:hover, :visited:hover {...}`

Comment: They seem to behave the same to me. What difference are you referring to?

Comment: It seems to be working as you want it to, and I tested it in Opera as well.

Comment: aha... ok thank you guys.  i couldnt understand why it seems strange to me but i didnt take the visited enough into account..
thanks for the notes!     now i should just find a better way of doing this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **a:visited** ends up being more specific than **:hover** since it has a tagname as well... your "#" links might not get flagged as visited?

Comment: you are right. thats actually why i thoughts its not working correctly, but it does. hashes do get flagged though, but i dont want that..

Answer (score 0):

WHy don;t you change the css to

```
a:hover
```

Answer (score 0):

in case someone is intersted, what i was missing was the css rules' order. plus a psuedo:psuedo rule

`a, a:active, a:visited {color: #765; text-decoration: none;}

:hover, :visited:hover  { color: #ff5e99; text-decoration:overline; background: #222}`

thanks fo the tips